# Add value in existing row using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have 2 array that I need to copy in excel starting from 2nd row but Column no is different.

1st array is copied successfully, but for second array when I am doing 
row =sheet.createRow(i) and trying to copy

It is actually overwriting the 1st array value.

```
public int setCellData(String[][] data,String LBorCH,int LastLBStartPoint){
    int lastrow = 0;
    try
    {
        //Find last row filled in Excel
        lastrow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        //Row count array
        int dataRows = data.length;

        //Column count
        //for loop for iterating over the data
        if(LBorCH =="LB")
        {
            for(int i=0;i<dataRows;i++)
            {
                int dataColumn = data[i].length;

                i=i+1+lastrow;
                row =sheet.createRow(i);
                i=i-1-lastrow;

                for(int j=0;j<dataColumn;j++)
                {
                    String fillData = data[i][j];
                    j = j+2;
                    cell = row.createCell(j);
                    j=j-2;
                    //Set value into cell
                    cell.setCellValue(fillData);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<dataRows;i++)
            {
                int dataColumn = data[i].length;

                i=i+1+LastLBStartPoint;
                row =sheet.createRow(i);
                i=i-1-LastLBStartPoint;

                for(int j=0;j<dataColumn;j++)
                {
                    String fillData = data[i][j];
                    j = j+5;
                    cell = row.createCell(j);
                    j=j-5;
                    //Set value into cell
                    cell.setCellValue(fillData); 
                }
            }

        }

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return lastrow;
}
```

[This is image of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lavGh.png)

LogicBroker section in excel is completed, I have to copy array in CommerceHub section which is coming from different class and go to else section in my code.

Please help me on this

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: 1st If section is working fine and copying data successfully, same function is getting called from 2 different class with different array.  When It is going to else it is trying to create new row to copy second array and at that time it is overwriting first array data.

Comment: for `row =sheet.createRow(i);` why not do something like `row =sheet.createRow(++lastrow);`?  This looks shaky to me `i=i+1+lastrow;
                row =sheet.createRow(i);
                i=i-1-lastrow;`.

Comment: Change your `if` condition to `LBorCH.equals("LB")` or even `LBorCh.equalsIgnoreCase("LB")`.

Comment: row =sheet.createRow(++lastrow);  will also create a new row, but here I don't want to create a new row or else existing data in that row will gets deleted, I just want to append new cell in existing row.